# python sum columns in matrix

Tags: python, matrix, sum

Here there is a piece of my script. What this should do is opening a matrix (in the file matrix_seeds_to_all_targets) and sum all the elements in each column (at the end I should get a 1xN array). What I get instead is an error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'sum'. Could you please give me any insight on this?

```
def collapse_probtrack_results(waytotal_file, matrix_file):
    with open(waytotal_file) as f:
        waytotal = int(f.read())
    f = open(wayfile_template + roi + "/matrix_seeds_to_all_targets")
    l = [map(int, line.split(',')) for line in f if line.strip() != ""]
    collapsed = l.sum(axis=0) / waytotal * 100.
    return collapsed
    print (collapsed)
```

Answer (score 0):

As the message says: lists don't have a method named `sum`.  It isn't clear just what you are trying to do on that line, so can't be more helpful than that.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use numpy instead of trying to sum over lists:

```
import numpy as np

matrix = np.random.randint(0, 100, (3, 6)) //read in your matrix file here

newMatrix = np.sum(matrix, axis=0)

print newMatrix
```

which will give you something like:

```
[168  51  23 115 208  54]
```

Without numpy, you would have to use something like a list comprehension to go over the "columns" in your lists to sum them. Python's list sum works on lists, which isn't what you have if you have 1) a matrix and 2) want to do the summing over columns

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried to use your suggestion, however I get the following error:                                                                                                   
sum = a.sum
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'sum'

Comment: You shouldnt be getting a list error with the above. In my code, you have to import your data as an actual numpy array, and not a list or nested list. my `matrix` is not a list like in your original code. You will have to load the datafile using one of numpys `fromfile`, `genfromtext`, `loadtxt` methods to get it into the correct form before you try to sum. Which you use depends on the format of the original matrix file you have

Answer (score 0):

I think that the instruction `l.sum()` is wrong. The function used to sum over a list is `sum` and must be used as in this sample:

```
myList = [1, 2, 3]
sum(myList) # will return 6
myList.sum() # will throw an error
```

If you want to select a given column, you can that list comprehension: `[row[columnID] for row in A]`

So, for instance, that code wil sum over the different rows of a 2D array named l.

```
numCols = len(l[0])
result = []
for i in range(numCols)
    result.append(sum([row[i] for row in l]))

print(result)
```

Also there seems that in your code there's a print after a return. I think it will never execute ;)